# Pattern-matching function

Tags: beginner, scala

I am new to Scala and I have written a function which uses pattern matching to filter words based on some conditions.  It seems to work correctly but I am suspect that I haven't used the Scala pattern matching in the best way.  I think this because each of my cases contain an `if` statement.  I have not seen any examples where people use `if` statements in pattern matching functions so I'm thinking there might be a better way of doing this.  Or maybe this particular usage does not fit well with pattern matching.

```
def getImportance(token:String,stopWords:Set[String])={
    token match{
      case t if t.length()==1 => 0
      case t if t.length()>15 => 0
      case t if t.matches("\\p{Punct}+") => 0
      case t if stopWords.contains(t.toLowerCase()) => 0
      case _ => 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Zero-length words get assigned an Importance of 1. I'm not sure that is correct.

Comment: 'token' is actually the output from a tokenizer which would not output zero-length words, so that case would never occur.

Comment: Hmmm. I've heard that before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that using pattern matching is necessary in this case, you only have a few simple conditions that can be better represented with a simple `if`. See what you think about this solution:

```
def getImportance(token: String, stopWords: Set[String]) =
  if (token.length() == 1 || token.length() > 15 ||
    token.matches("\\p{Punct}+") ||
    stopWords.contains(token.toLowerCase()))
      0
  else
      1
```

I believe it is simpler and easier to read. I think using patter matching for these simple cases only hinders the understanding of the code ;)